# appending array in objective c

Tags: objective-c

i read this command from cocoadev.com but was not able to get it plz help me in explaining what this line of code do

```
[array addObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:15]];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use `NSMutableArray` instead of `NSArray` to use the method `addObject:`.

Answer (score 1):

It adds a number object with the integer value of 15 to the collection (presumably an NSMutableArray) called `array`.